# "Cannot GET" Error on Firebase Cloud Functions + Express sample

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I'm new to firebase and trying to make simple Cloud Functions + Express sample from video below to work.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOeioOKUKI8

When I try to serve my index.js from http://localhost:5000/timestamp, I get following error.

> Cannot GET /{my-project-id}/us-central1/app/timestamp

In my terminal I get following output.

> ⚠  Default "firebase-admin" instance created!
>   i  functions: Finished "app" in ~1s
>   [hosting] Rewriting /timestamp to http://localhost:5001/{my-project-id}/us-central1/app for local Function app

But if I deploy, It works as expected and it will show my timestamp.

My current code is below.

index.js

```js
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.get('/timestamp', (request, response) => {
  response.send(`${Date.now()}`);
});

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

firebase.json

```json
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "rewrites": [{
      "source": "/timestamp",
      "function": "app"
    }],
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

If I rewrite part of my index.js to something like,

```js
app.get('/{my-project-id}/us-central1/app/timestamp', (request, response) => {
  response.send(`${Date.now()}`);
});
```

it will show my timestamp when I access http://localhost:5000/timestamp.
Anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On my side, i was try to develop a Rest API with firebase cloud functions. I have got same error. If i push my code firebase servers via 'Firebase deploy' It was running what i want. But when i run on my local server via 'firebase serve --only functions, hosting' command there will be always error like Cannot GET and not run. I was try your code and same here. I found a ridiculously simple solution for that and run on my side. Could you try on locally,

```
 app.get('*/timestamp', (request, response) => {
   response.send(`${Date.now()}`);
 });
```

Just add * before the your path.

**UPDATE :**

'firebase-tools' has been updated. If you update your buggy version that 6.9.2 to 6.10.0 the problem has been fixed.

For update latest firebase-tools:

```
npm i -g firebase-tools
```

Comment: Your answer was also helpful as a workaround to solve the issue with latest firebase-tools.
But I'll make @Noncenzt 's answer as accepted answer, since it doesn't require any change on my production code.
Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the update! will use the latest version of firebase-tools :)

Comment: I have the same problem, change '/my-path' work '*/my-path' for me! Thanks!

Comment: this is the answer; this is what is known as 'attention to detail'

Answer (score 7):

For those coming here in recent times, `firebase emulators:start` is default way to start if you use `firebase init` to create your firebase functions.

Adding `*/` is of course one of the way to go forward.

The reason for `Cannot /GET /*` could be the way firebase exports the api.

After creating the api,

```
app.get('/app/testapi', (req, res) => {
  res.send({ 'status': 0});
});
```

when it is exported as `exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);`
the actual api becomes `app/app/testapi` as firebase exports the api on `app`, (`export.app`).

You can remove the extra `app` from here:

```
app.get('/app/testapi', (req, res) => {
  res.send({ 'status': 0});
});
```

which then becomes :

```
app.get('/testapi', (req, res) => {
  res.send({ 'status': 0});
});
```

This will be available in `app/testapi/`.

Comment: This has saved me big time, thank you so much for writing this answer

Answer (score 3):

For some newcomers, start using `firebase emulators:start` to test functions locally before deploying as this is a part of new Firebase Emulator Suite. `firebase serve` is deprecated now

Answer (score -1):

I face the same problem as you. And I fix it by revert firebase-tools to 6.8.0 and the problem solve !

`npm install --global firebase-tools@6.8.0`

As for the ref: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1280

Comment: Great! Downgrading my firebase-tools resolved the problem!
I'll keep my eye on the issue you provided for future fix on firebase-tools. Thanks!